# compile and load reactjs component file dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dynamic

I want to load reactjs file dynamically in browser either through making **script** tag or through **ajax** (I don't know which method works good for my scenario)

and then I want to render component from that file let say my file has component

```
import React from 'react';

class D11 extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    console.log("loaded D1 constructor")
}
render() {
    console.log("rendering D1")
    return (

        <div>
            D1 loaded 
        </div>

    );
}};
export default D11;
```

should I compile this file into js with some ***webpack*** before loading how can I do that and what is best method for this I want to achieve behavior like in these blogs [dynamic loading](https://medium.com/@samarjit.samanta/react-dynamic-plugins-loading-e45905aa00a7) and this [nylas link](https://www.nylas.com/blog/react-plugins/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React.Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) or [dynamic import](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/code-splitting/#appjs) are 2 possible options.

Comment: Thanks @jeggettx I've used import :)